# Very strange bug with auto-scroll when typing text

Tags: html, css

Here is example page: http://texting.zz.mu/

At the bottom you can see `div` with `contenteditable=true`.

Try to type some text inside. Then `#talkTab` block scrolls!

I'm really confused. Why can it be?
I can't show only part of code because i dont know in what part this bug is.
I know, that there is much code, but...

Help me please, i will "like" all your answers :D

Comment: are you okay to use jquery..??

I've got your bug fixed

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See I've fixed your problem, I've used a little jquery to structure your design, you can see the running example of your code

Click the link : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvzzyr1e/)

**jQuery:**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var w,h;                
            $(window).resize(function(){
                w = $(window).width();
                h = $(window).height();
                $('.window_height').height(h-50);
                $('.dialog_height').height(h-0);
            }).resize();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CSS you need.

```
overflow-x : auto //Since your div's height and width are defined.
```

The scrollbar can be triggered with overflow-x in you case and it can be set to any of visible, hidden, scroll, auto, or inherit. You are currently looking at these two:

**auto** - This value will look at the width and height of the box. If they are defined, it won't let the box expand past those boundaries. Instead (if the content exceeds those boundaries), it will create a scrollbar for either boundary (or both) that exceeds its length.

**scroll** - This values forces a scrollbar, no matter what, even if the content does not exceed the boundary set. If the content doesn't need to be scrolled, the bar will appear as "disabled" or non-interactive.

Also in your case the problem is because of this attribute in **talkTab**

```
overflow-y : scroll;
```

Comment: But when i'm typing somethink block is still scrolling.. Where i should place that CSS? For what element?

Comment: you have to add it in #message of the div.

Comment: Seems you have do Shift+Refresh to see that working.

Comment: What browser do you using? I've cleaned my cache, still not working.

Comment: I am using chrome. You can use firebug or any tool to debug.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understood the problem? When i'm typing,  block  `#talkTab` automatically scrolls to bottom. Try to change zoom at 200% (you may have too big resolution).

Comment: In talkTab CSS overflow-y : scroll; is the problem .

Answer (score 1):

Lose the height: calc(100% - 110px); in your CSS, if you're okay with jQuery to fix the height then I can give you a better solution, plus the structure is bit of a mess, if you could just lemme know if jQuery can be used or not..

Comment: Yeah, i can use JQuery.